# Ruby Opscode Chef API - POST authenticate_user

Tags: ruby, rest, post, chef-infra

Im trying to authenticate one user using Opscode Chef API

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'chef/config'
  require 'chef/log'
  require 'chef/rest'

  chef_server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1'
  client_name = 'admin'
  signing_key_filename = '/root/admin.pem'

  rest = Chef::REST.new(chef_server_url, client_name, signing_key_filename)
  puts rest.get_rest('/organizations/example/users/admin')


  puts rest.get_rest('/organizations/example/clients')
  puts rest.get_rest('/organizations/example/users')
  bugabuga = {"username" => "admin","password" => "4dm1n1str4t0r"}

  puts rest.post_rest('/organizations/example/authenticate_user', bugabuga)
```

But im receiving a 404 for the POST method.

This is the output

```
  {"username"=>"admin", "email"=>"the_good@example.com", "display_name"=>"the administrator", "first_name"=>"the", "last_name"=>"administrator", "middle_name"=>"", "public_key"=>"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtilYX/92ZuEPcP7D2VQ4\nKyU5koWvzS9SkWwkvRI8nmH6C+ELWz9iDfwCb5r4ioZUYx56i1JB/srhdBQMhDKN\na2qyoqaEiIFkIKKJIqAg1h5UHDjxL/8SF9BTdcoMyDmr7tDd2gpfEOc1+ILaOSca\nY3TjfPbdM+eo5jyEuxGz+OnhuPx1KUwTmMFpVkNXR38R+sbzQWKJrjMhCo/6aIZk\niutH7MCeO9Ff60WeYd+B6PSz+r0UaryPaViFwIGk1AYuTRQJ+9yUAwJwGMIqAUQo\nzZPcgp4tSpqHLojtlDlNvPXRFgtqKMzsndBhbZSoiD1g4ZhWvTbLZlHo9wUQeEXj\nDQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n\n"}
  {"example-validator"=>"https://127.0.0.1/organizations/example/clients/example-validator", "node01"=>"https://127.0.0.1/organizations/example/clients/node01"}
  {"user"=>{"username"=>"admin"}}
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2633:in `error!': 404 "Not Found" (Net::HTTPServerException)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:199:in `block in raw_http_request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:280:in `retriable_rest_request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:164:in `raw_http_request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:158:in `api_request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:118:in `post'
from test.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

From the official documentation: https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#authenticate-user

I cant make it work.

Any idea of what im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a few days.. I have found the correct way to query the Chef API for this POST method.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'chef/config'
require 'chef/log'
require 'chef/rest'

chef_server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1'
client_name = 'admin'
signing_key_filename = '/root/admin.pem'

rest = Chef::REST.new(chef_server_url, client_name, signing_key_filename)

data = {"username" => "admin", "password" => "4dm1n1str4t0r" }
rest.post_rest('authenticate_user', data)
```

Now im receiving a 403, but at least the URL path is correct, I will put the answer once I fix the forbidden thing..